# How to manipulate AMP State based on responses from a drop down

Tags: amp-html, amp-bind

There is a nice example https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/linked_dropdowns/ on the AMP By Example site and this works well however I'm trying to understand how to make this more general and have more than two drop downs and am finding it hard to find the correct syntax to manipulate the AMP.setState.

In the example

```html
<amp-list width="auto"
    height="25"
    layout="fixed-height"
    src="https://ampbyexample.com/json/linked_dropdowns.json">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
      <label for="country">Country:</label>
      <select id="country"
        on="
      change:
        AMP.setState({
          cities: dropdown.items[0].countries.filter(x => x.name == event.value)[0]
        })">
        <option value="">Choose a country</option>
        {{#countries}}
        <option value="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
        {{/countries}}
      </select>
    </template>
  </amp-list>
  <amp-list width="auto"
    height="25"
    layout="fixed-height"
    [src]="cities || 'https://ampbyexample.com/json/linked_dropdowns.json'"
    src="https://ampbyexample.com/json/linked_dropdowns.json">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
      <label for="city">City:</label>
      <select [disabled]="!cities"
        disabled
        id="city">
        {{^cities}}
        <option value=""></option>{{/cities}} {{#cities.0}}
        <option value="">Choose a city</option>{{/cities.0}} {{#cities}}
        <option value="{{.}}">{{.}}</option>{{/cities}}
      </select>
    </template>
  </amp-list>
  <amp-state id="dropdown"
    src="https://ampbyexample.com/json/linked_dropdowns.json"></amp-state>
```

It had takes the result of the dropdown and usesd that to create a new element in setState of cities that is then used in the next amp-list.

I can't tell from the code and description how to repeat this so that when the second element is selected that allows a further selection (sub selection to be made).

The element:

```html
on="change:AMP.setState({cities: dropdown.items[0].countries.filter(x => x.name == event.value)[0]})"
```

And

```html
<amp-list width="auto"
    height="25"
    layout="fixed-height"
    [src]="cities || 'https://ampbyexample.com/json/linked_dropdowns.json'"
    src="https://ampbyexample.com/json/linked_dropdowns.json">
```

works but doesn't explain what is happening and how this could be used to take the second result and extract further options.

Anyone have any ideas or examples on how this might be made to work?

Answer (score 0):

First, I am going to assume when you say "take the second result and extract further options" that you are intending to add an additional `select` option to filter (e.g. museums within a city).

In order to do this, first you need a data set which accommodates the additional information. This could be a modification of the current data set or an entirely new data set endpoint.

For ease sake, let's modify the current set of data [like so](https://api.myjson.com/bins/xaus5). Once we have the new set of data, we can create the correct markup to show three dropdowns in a sequence ([example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/kopepasah/full/ed2dc309231bc2186e886db210f32c1b/)).

NOTE: Currently there is a bug that resets the city select right after selecting. My guess is there is something triggering the change event on the country select (which resets the city select), but did not have a chance to dig into the issue (help welcome).

Comment: Thanks - the JSON file doesn't seem to be loading.

As I have been playing with this the issues I am having are focusing on the next step, you select the drop downs and now want to (say go to a URL).

Its possible to have a button:

<button class="ampstart-btn" on="tap:AMP.navigateTo(url=theURL)" >
 Go to {{dropdown.items[0].season}}{{^dropdown.items[0].season}}selected season{{/dropdown.items[0].season}}
</button>

But getting the data out of the JSON construct and playing with it seems to me complicated - but that may be me not knowing the underlying constructs